# How to determine if a point is inside an ellipse that is inside a rectangle?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, drawing, shapes

Using C# and .NET... I want to monitor whether any pixels on my computer screen change to a certain color, but only pixels within a "fixed" region of the screen, which is in the shape of an ellipse.  Given an x,y coordinate that represents a pixel somewhere on the screen, (from 0,0 to 1919, 1079) how can I tell if it is within the ellipse on the screen?

Specifically let's say my screen is 1920 wide x 1080 pixels high.  And the ellipse is 1100 pixels wide and 700 pixels high, and that the top of the ellipse starts 200 pixels from the very top of the screen and the very left of the ellipse starts 350 pixels from the left edge of the screen.

Given the above, can someone please provide an example method in C# that takes a Point and returns true if the point falls within this ellipse and false if otherwise? I found some examples online of how to detect whether a point falls within an ellipse but was unsure of how to tie this in specifically to my need here.

Also as a 2nd part of the question - in the near future I may need to define multiple areas of the screen besides this one ellipse. So for instance it may be if the Point falls within the ellipse or within other regions of the screen that may be in the shape of a ellipse or squire or polygon.  Please don't over-complicate the code snippet just for this part - the main question is just focused on the ellipse. But in case it is relatively easy to make it support the ellipse as well as another other defined regions of the screen that would be good to know too. Thank you in advance for your help.

Please be detailed as you can in the example and explanation, as I am a novice programmer and much of this is over my head.

Comment: That's more math than C#

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76457/check-if-a-point-is-within-an-ellipse This should actually help you - it should be possible to write a program out of the equation. But avoid asking for the whole code, minimize to specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [GraphicsPath.IsVisible()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d20k495d(v=vs.110).aspx)?...

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath Ellipse = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
Ellipse.AddEllipse(350, 200, 1100, 700);

Point pt = new Point(x, y); // get your point from somewhere
if (Ellipse.IsVisible(pt)) // test to see if the point is contained by the ellipse
{
    // ...do something in here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Work out the equation for your ellipse, based on its major and minor
axes, a=1100/2=550 and b=700/2=350 in your case, and its center coordinates, which are
(cx,cy)=(900,550). Then use the equation of an ellipse:
If (x,y) satisfies

- (x-cx)^2 / a^2 + (y-cy)^2 / b^2 <= 1

then (x,y) is in the ellipse.